# Jasmine and angular mocks : mocking a service that handles local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

I have one service called wd$cache, that is basically a wrapper for localStorage.setItem and get.item.

Now I'm trying to test a controller that uses that service to achieve a certain result. The main problem is that I have an IF statement that gets triggered only if you have localstorage set already which is driving me nuts! (we are doing TDD here)

SERVICE

```
(function () {

angular
    .module('hub')
    .controller('promotionNotificationCtrl', promotionNotificationCtrl);

promotionNotificationCtrl.$inject = [
    'hub$promotions',
    'hub$client',
    'wd$cache'
];

function promotionNotificationCtrl(
    hub$promotions,
    hub$client,
    wd$cache) {

    var vm = this;
    activate();

    //////////

    function activate () {

        hub$promotions.get(hub$client.brand, hub$client.subbrand).success(function (data) {

            if (!wd$cache.get('hub$notification')) {

                wd$cache.add('before', 123);
            } else {

                wd$cache.add('after', 321);
            }
        });
    }
}
})();
```

TEST

```
describe('The promotion notification controller', function () {

var controller,
    hub$client,
    $httpBackend,
    wd$cache,
    mockData = [{

        "foo": "bar"
    },
    {
        "faa": "boo"
    }];


beforeEach(module('hub'));
beforeEach(module('wired.core'));

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {

    hub$client = {

        brand: 'bw',
        subbrand: 'plus'
    };

    wd$cache = {

        add: function () {

        },

        get: function () {

        }
    };

    $provide.value('hub$client', hub$client);
    $provide.value('wd$cache', wd$cache);
    spyOn(wd$cache, 'add');
}));

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$httpBackend_, _hub$promotions_) {

    controller = $controller('promotionNotificationCtrl');
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    hub$promotions = _hub$promotions_;

    // request
    $httpBackend.expectGET("/umbraco/api/promotions/get/?brand=bw&lang=en&subbrand=plus").respond(200, mockData);
    $httpBackend.flush();
}));

it('should attempt to add a cache with a "before" key if no previous "hub$notification" cache was found', function () {


    expect(wd$cache.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('before', 123); //WORKING
})

it('should attempt to add a cache with a "after" key if a previous "hub$notification" cache was found', function () {

    localStorage.setItem('hub$notification');
    wd$cache.add('hub$notification');

    expect(wd$cache.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('after', 123); // NOT WORKING
    // CANT GET THROUGH THE IF STATEMENT
})
});
```

Basically I can never get to 'Test Cases' after BeforeEach block, whatever I do. I've tried everything, since mocking it to use actual storage.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the error that you are getting in the Karma test-runner?

Comment: Completely forgot about that!
Expected wd$cache.add to have been called with 'after' but actual calls were 'before', 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a mock implementation that is already filled with some data:

```
var cache = {};    

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    // ...
    wd$cache = {
        add: function (key, value) {
            cache[key] = value;
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return cache[key];
        }
    };

    // add initial data here or in the individual tests, e.g.


    // ...
}));
```

To set up the cache properly for a specific testcase you can use the `cache` field like this:

```
cache['hub$notification'] = 'whatever value makes sense here';
```

Of course you can also do this in `beforeEach`.

Currently you are trying to do it like this:

```
wd$cache.add('hub$notification');
expect(wd$cache.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('after', 123);
```

This is problematic for two reasons:

- You are not updating the cache because you are spying on the `add` method without `.andCallThrough()`. You should fix this (add `.andCallThrough()` after spy creation) otherwise updates from the controller will not affect the cache.
- The spy records your call instead. You don't want this for setup code because it makes subsequent assertions more complicated.

Comment: That only works if I set cache['hub$notification'] = 123; in the before each, which will make the first test break since there's a cache available! 

    it('should attempt to add a cache with a "after" key if a previous "hub$notification" cache was found', function () {

        wd$cache.hub$notification = 123;
        expect(wd$cache.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('after', 123);
    })

Comment: That was a silly comment! But basically by doing that you end up only fulfilling one of the it statements since the only way of getting that working is putting it on the before each!

Comment: Simply move the `var cache = {}` to the outer scope. You can then modify the cache content in each individual test not just in the `beforeEach`.

Comment: It was outside on my code since the beginning. Even if I set a new cache on each IT it gets only the first value. Not sure why!

Comment: I updated my answer. It now includes an explanation why your current approach does not work.